# OData Item service Support in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: sitecore-api, odata

For one of our new application[non-sitecore] we need some data from Sitecore Instance which is on version 8.2.

We are looking for the available API options, Is OData Item Service is supportable with version 8.2 or we need to go with Item service ? 
We require only Read access.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go with Item service, oData is not available in Sitecore 8.2, here is a quote from Sitecore doc for the services available in Sitecore.Services.Client in 8.2:

> Sitecore.Services.Client provides two services:
>
> ```
> ItemService: this service gives you access to regular Sitecore items.
>
> EntityService: this service gives you access to business objects that you define.
> ```

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/sitecore-services-client.html